# using django-email-as-username how can I return with a message to the user?

Tags: django

I am trying to use [django-email-as-username](https://github.com/dabapps/django-email-as-username) and I can't find a way to return to the login page with a message for the user in case the data provided by the user is wrong.

this my `urls.py`

```
url(r'^login$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'authentication_form': EmailAuthenticationForm}, name='login'),
```

this is my `views.py`

```
def login_user(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        if email and password:
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                message = 'No such user'
        else:
            message = 'both email and password are required!'
    else:
        message = 'wrong method!'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've made an error in that you're providing your own `login_user` view in your `views.py` module, but linking to Django's `django.contrib.auth.views.login` in your URL conf.

You should probably just use `django.contrib.auth.views.login` as the login view.

You'll also need to provide a `registration/login.html` template.  You'll be able to get at the error information, as the form is passed through to the context. You can use the [admin's login template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html) as an example.

Comment: thank you. That was my first attempt. I then realized that POST requests are not handled by the `django.contrib.auth.views.login` (GET requests, do however). Maybe it is because `django-email-as-username` uses its own auth backend.

Comment: "POST requests are not handled" - Did you mean to write "GET requests are not handled"? I can see that POST requests are: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L37

Comment: "Maybe it is because django-email-as-username uses its own auth backend." - I'm not sure what you mean by that.  The auth backend that gets used won't affect the template or template context.

Comment: I know it sounds strange. I did many tests and POST was not handled by the `django.contrib.auth.views.login` view. I will post my template and the terminal output. Maybe the problem is because I did something stupid.

Comment: Ok, I did everything from scratch. It now works. `django.contrib.auth.views.login` handles POST requests normally. I don't know what was wrong before. But you were right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case of authentication failure, you have to render/redirect your own login page with `{{ message }}`